# Why does my foreach take forever to load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

This piece of code is run when i hit the submit button on my site to filter out results by address. But for some reason it takes forever for the page to reload,
if anyone has any ideas how i can optimize my code please let me know.

I added 2 functions below that should explain what they do better.

Thanks in advance.

```
  $location = !empty($_POST['saddress']) ? $_POST['saddress'] : "NA";

if ($location != "NA")
    $display = true;
$street = explode(',', $location);
$users = get_users('orderby=nicename&role=employer');
global $wpdb;

$location = $_POST['saddress'];

$street = explode(',', $location);
$cat = $_GET['specializingin'];
//$specilty = 'specialties_'. $cat;


$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'scategory',
            'value' => $_GET['specializingin'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'specialties',
            'value' => ($_GET['specialitiesin'] == 'All Specialties' ? '' : $_GET['specialitiesin']),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
);
//p($args);
$search_users = get_users($args);
//p($search_users);
$formattedAddress = prettyAddress($location);

foreach ($search_users as $k => $user):
    if (!empty($street[0])) {
        $db = prettyAddress(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'company_address', true));
        $match = matchAddress($formattedAddress, $db, count($street));
        if ($match == false)
            unset($search_users[$k]);
    }
endforeach;


$search_users = custom_sorting($search_users);
```

**All of code:**

```
<form name="jobfilter" action="" method="post">
<div class="filter-srch">

    <input id="locationjf" name="saddress" placeholder="Type desired location" class="search-text1" value="<?= $location != 'NA' ? $location : '' ?>" type="text">

</div>


<div class="filter-srch">

    <input class="job-filter-btn" value="" type="submit">

</div>
```

```
function prettyAddress($address) {
$location = array();
if (empty($address))
    return $location;

$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key=AIzaSyCR9coRcI1OXCDowXtMYsSNPYAizM8wZD0";
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
if (!isset($result['results'][0]['address_components']))
    return $location;
$components = $result['results'][0]['address_components'];
foreach ($result['results'][0]['address_components'] as $component) {
    switch ($component['types']) {
        case in_array('street_number', $component['types']):
            $location['street_number'] = $component['long_name'];
            break;
        case in_array('route', $component['types']):
            $location['street'] = $component['long_name'];
            break;
        case in_array('sublocality', $component['types']):
            $location['sublocality'] = $component['long_name'];
            break;
        case in_array('locality', $component['types']):
            $location['city'] = $component['long_name'];
            break;
        case in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $component['types']):
            $location['admin_2'] = $component['long_name'];
            break;
        case in_array('administrative_area_level_1', $component['types']):
            $location['state'] = $component['long_name'];
            $location['state_code'] = $component['short_name'];
            break;
        case in_array('postal_code', $component['types']):
            $location['postal_code'] = $component['long_name'];
            break;
        case in_array('country', $component['types']):
            $location['country'] = $component['long_name'];
            $location['country_code'] = $component['short_name'];
            break;
    }
}
return $location;
```

}

```
function matchAddress($search, $db, $count = 0) {
    $match = false;
    if (isset($db['country'])) {
        if (strlen($db['country']) > 2) {
            if (stripos($db['country'], $search['country']) !== FALSE)
                $match = TRUE;
            else
                $match = FALSE;
        } else {
            if (stripos($db['country'], $search['country_code']) !== FALSE)
                $match = TRUE;
            else
                $match = FALSE;
        }
    }
    if ($count == 1)
        return $match;
    if (isset($db['state'])) {
        if (strlen($db['state']) > 2) {
            if (stripos($db['state'], $search['state']) !== FALSE)
                $match = TRUE;
            else
                $match = FALSE;
        } else {
            if (stripos($db['state'], $search['state_code']) !== FALSE)
                $match = TRUE;
            else
                $match = FALSE;
        }
    }
    if ($count == 2)
        return $match;
    if (isset($db['city'])) {
        if (stripos($db['city'], $search['city']) !== FALSE)
            $match = TRUE;
        else
            $match = FALSE;
    }
    return $match;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have two db round trips in your foreach loop.

Comment: your running 2 queries on every user, rather than just one query, which should be all you need.

Comment: Could you explain further, thanks.

Comment: trying to explain further: `get_user_meta()` and `matchAddress()` look like they both run a query behind. Yet we don't see these methods, thus can not really say _how_ to optimize that.

Comment: i dont even think you need to run one on every user vs just ONE full stop. but i simply cant tell based on what i see above

Comment: I updated my question with more code, please have a look.

Comment: hitting a remote api for every user is going to be a performance killer, do it once and store the results.

Comment: Thanks, a code example would be much appreciated. You can also view what i am working on here https://energypages.com/specialization?specializingin=energy_supply_and_distribution&specialitiesin= the location filter on the sidebar is the form

Comment: You are using query to database in foreach loop and that seems main reason of slow down of script. You should consider to take the query out of loop, save data in an array indexed by user id and get data from that array when required. This way script would execute faster however would take more memory depending upon number of records returned from db.

Comment: SynapseIndia - looking at the code above you can see i use  ( get_users() ) which is a wordpress function. the output is: Array ( [0] => WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 370 etc.......

Comment: For readability, i would advise you to write your arrays as `['item 1' => ['key' => 'value']];` instead of `array('item 1' => array('key' => 'value'));`, with offcourse the proper indention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a cron job to fetch the data from the API, store the results in multiple text files and then fetch the data from the text files which is much faster than querying the API multiple times.

**query geocode api daily cron job setup**

```
add_action('geocode_daily_event', 'geocode_daily');

function geocode_activation() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'geocode_daily_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'twenty_two_hours', 'geocode_daily_event');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'geocode_activation');
function geocode_daily(){
    $args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'company_address'
            ),
        ),
    );

    //query execution
    $search_companies = get_users($args);

    foreach ($search_companies as $user){
        $address =  get_user_meta($user->ID, 'company_address', true);
        $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);

        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key={YOUR GEOCODE API KEY HERE}";

        $cache_path = get_stylesheet_directory().'/geocode-cache/';
        $filename = $cache_path.md5($url);

        $result  = file_get_contents($url);
        file_put_contents($filename, $result );
    }
}
```

**Function to query the cached files**

```
function prettyAddress($address) {
    $location = array();
    if (empty($address))
        return $location;

    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key=AIzaSyCntthdn3101F8RC8RLzv9QxF_tmCvdqNg";

    $cache_path = get_stylesheet_directory().'/geocode-cache/';
    $filename = $cache_path.md5($url);

    // && ( time() - 84600 < filemtime($filename) )
    if( file_exists($filename) ){
        $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);

        if (!isset($result['results'][0]['address_components']))
            return $location;
        $components = $result['results'][0]['address_components'];
        foreach ($result['results'][0]['address_components'] as $component) {
            switch ($component['types']) {
                case in_array('street_number', $component['types']):
                    $location['street_number'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('route', $component['types']):
                    $location['street'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('sublocality', $component['types']):
                    $location['sublocality'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('locality', $component['types']):
                    $location['city'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $component['types']):
                    $location['admin_2'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('administrative_area_level_1', $component['types']):
                    $location['state'] = $component['long_name'];
                    $location['state_code'] = $component['short_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('postal_code', $component['types']):
                    $location['postal_code'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('country', $component['types']):
                    $location['country'] = $component['long_name'];
                    $location['country_code'] = $component['short_name'];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $result  = file_get_contents($url);
        file_put_contents($filename, $result );
        $result  = json_decode($result , true);

        if (!isset($result['results'][0]['address_components']))
            return $location;
        $components = $result['results'][0]['address_components'];
        foreach ($result['results'][0]['address_components'] as $component) {
            switch ($component['types']) {
                case in_array('street_number', $component['types']):
                    $location['street_number'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('route', $component['types']):
                    $location['street'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('sublocality', $component['types']):
                    $location['sublocality'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('locality', $component['types']):
                    $location['city'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('administrative_area_level_2', $component['types']):
                    $location['admin_2'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('administrative_area_level_1', $component['types']):
                    $location['state'] = $component['long_name'];
                    $location['state_code'] = $component['short_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('postal_code', $component['types']):
                    $location['postal_code'] = $component['long_name'];
                    break;
                case in_array('country', $component['types']):
                    $location['country'] = $component['long_name'];
                    $location['country_code'] = $component['short_name'];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $location;
}
```