# How can i remove integer index from array

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i access the ID value without having to use the index?

in my code i do this ( $array[0]['data']['ID'] ) to access the ID value, i have many users and having to access them individually by the integer index is time consuming.

I prefer not to use a foreach loop because i my code i make calls to a remote API and it will query the API for each user which kills performane.

If i can convert the current array to one without the index that would be great and just access the ID value through ( $array['data']['ID'] ).

```
[0] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [ID] => 370 


[1] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [ID] => 405
```

I found that the code below lags my page load tremendously:

```
foreach ($search_users as $k => $user):
    if (!empty($street[0])) {
        $db = prettyAddress(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'company_address', true));
        $match = matchAddress($formattedAddress, $db, count($street));
        if ($match == false)
            unset($search_users[$k]);
    }
endforeach;
```

It is referenced in my question here:
[Why does my foreach take forever to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866323/why-does-my-foreach-take-forever-to-load)

```
$location = !empty($_POST['saddress']) ? $_POST['saddress'] : "NA";
    $display = false;
    if ($location != "NA")
        $display = true;
    global $wpdb;

    $location = $_POST['saddress'];

    $street = explode(',', $location);
    $cat = $_GET['specializingin'];

    $args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'scategory',
                'value' => $_GET['specializingin'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'specialties',
                'value' => ($_GET['specialitiesin'] == 'All Specialties' ? '' : $_GET['specialitiesin']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
        ),
    );

    $search_users = get_users($args);

    $formattedAddress = prettyAddress($location);
```

Comment: I don't understand what that `foreach` loop has to do with the rest of the question. It doesn't use `$array[0]['data']['ID']` anywhere.

Comment: What is `$street`?

Comment: Since `$street[0]` doesn't change during the loop, you should do that `if` before the loop: `if (!empty($street[0])) { foreach ... }`

Comment: Barmar i added the rest of my code

Comment: I still don't see anything that looks like `$array[0]['data']['ID']` in the code you added.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is what you i should have put: `$search_users[0]['data']['ID']` the get_users() function will output something like this: `Array ( [0] => WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 370`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a variable to the current element of the array:

```
$current = $array[0];
```

Then you can access

```
$current['data']['ID'];
```

If you need to be able to modify the array using this, you should use a reference:

```
$current =& $array[0];
```

you can do this in a loop:

```
foreach ($array as $current) {
    echo $current['data']['ID'];
}
```

Comment: That's the thing, i need to access all the array elements and not just the current one.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. What do you mean by `$array['data']['ID']` how is it supposed to know which array element to access?

Comment: If i use a foreach loop i can access the ID like this     
$array->ID without having to specify a key but since my code queries a remote API the loading time is a killer because it does it for each user

Comment: `->` is for objects, not arrays.

Comment: Have a look at this question i posted yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866323/why-does-my-foreach-take-forever-to-load

Comment: Sounds like you need an API that returns all the data, rather than requiring a separate call for each item. That's unrelated to how you access array elements once you have all the data loaded.

Comment: In this question it looks like the data is already loaded into the array.